# Using shutil.copytree to copy folder that already exists

Tags: python, directory, copy

I have the codes to copy folders with names that match the IDs on a csv list, it has been working well copying all the folders until it finds a folder with a name that already exists in the destination folder. I believe the issue comes from the following section of the codes,because I thought the `if` function should let `shutil.copytree` skip if it finds a foldername matches exactly with a folder in the destination folder.

```
save_path = r""
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    date = r["Date"]
    ID = r["ID"]
    survey_paths = findSurveys(path = SourcePath, survey_id = ID)
    for path in survey_paths:
        temp = path.split("\\")
        save_date = temp[-2]
        save_id = temp[-1]
        #compare if the path of previously saved survey equals the new one
        if save_path != rf"{DstPath}\{save_date}\{save_id}":
            shutil.copytree(path,rf"{DstPath}\{save_date}\{save_id}")
            save_path = rf'{DstPath}\{save_date}\{save_id}'
            print(save_path.split("\\")[-1]+ " ("+ save_path.split("\\")[-2]+ ")"" copied!")
```

The following is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "Z:\Python\DCPA\FolderCopy\FolderCopy.py", line 34, in <module>
    shutil.copytree(path,rf"{DstPath}\{save_date}\{save_id}")

  File "Z:\Apps\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 565, in copytree
    return _copytree(entries=entries, src=src, dst=dst, symlinks=symlinks,

  File "Z:\Apps\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 466, in _copytree
    os.makedirs(dst, exist_ok=dirs_exist_ok)

  File "Z:\Apps\Anaconda3\lib\os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)

FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'Y:\\P43_NEW\\2022-02-21\\112_1'
```

Comment: It looks like you're only comparing to the previous saved path rather than all directories previously saved in that directory. Are you only anticipating a single saved path at a time?

Comment: ah that might be why! Can the codes be modified somehow so it compares ALL directories in the desination folder?

Comment: I just posted an answer that should get you started on a solution

Answer (score 0):

You're potentially only checking against the last saved path!

I'd use the `os` package to check and see if the directory exists before attempting a save.

Here's a quick snippet of what occurs to me (its untested).

```
import os

if not os.path.isdir(r"path/to/folder"):
    save_path = (r"path/to/folder")
```

Here's a quick link to get you started on a fix also, if you need to hunt down more solutions when it comes to file stuff. Another option is to append the current time to the end of your folders so that every folder you create is unique every time.

```
from datetime import datetime

# earlier creation of the save path
save_path = save_path + datetime.now().strftime("%H%M%S"),
```

See [Python: Check if a File or Directory Exists](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-check-if-a-file-or-directory-exists-2/#:%7E:text=Check%20if%20a%20directory%20exists%20os.path.isdir%28%29%20method%20in,directory%20then%20the%20method%20will%20return%20True%20).

Answer (score 0):

You could use try, except insted If.

```py
try:
    shutil.copytree(path,rf"{DstPath}\{save_date}\{save_id}")
    save_path = rf'{DstPath}\{save_date}\{save_id}'
    print(save_path.split("\\")[-1]+ " ("+ save_path.split("\\")[-2]+ ")"" copied!")
    
except FileExistsError:
    pass
```